# ZMQError: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ipc, zeromq

I have an zmq function as below

```
def recieve_messages(self):
         string = self.sub_socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
         print('flow mod messages recieved {}'.format(string))
```

When I run the program however I get the following error.

```
  string = self.sub_socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
  File "socket.pyx", line 616, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:5961)
  File "socket.pyx", line 650, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv (zmq/core/socket.c:5832)
  File "socket.pyx", line 119, in zmq.core.socket._recv_copy (zmq/core/socket.c:1669)
ZMQError: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Can someone explain what is likely causing this error.